# Where to cut the throat for halal slaughter?

Tags: fiqh, dhabihah, eid-ul-adha

Is there some specific location along the neck where a cut must be made for it to be halal slaughter? Or can one cut anywhere along the neck?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Department Of Halal Certification](http://halalcertification.ie/islamic-method-of-slaughtering/):

> ***The windpipe (throat), food-tract (oesophagus) and the two jugular veins must be cut.***
>
> ***Slaughtering must be made in the neck from the front (chest) to the back.***

<sub>This is just a partial answer, I'll try to find evidence from the Hadith and Quran to suppprt this but if anyone finds it, feel free to edit this answer with the revelant quotations.</sub>

Comment: So there is no specific place? These run through the entire neck.

Comment: The requirement is for these parts to be cut so there is no specific place.

Comment: @user28669 I've found more informations which may help